# One of the methods in my class is working, but another method with the same syntax is not working(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

```
class Calculate():

def set_total_cost(self):
total_cost = 1000
self.__total_cost = total_cost

def get_total_cost(self):
return self.__total_cost

def set_down_pmt(self):
down_pmt = 0.25
self.__down_pmt = down_pmt

def get_down_pmt(self):
return self.__down_pmt


test = Calculate()
test.set_total_cost()
test.set_down_pmt()

print(test.get_total_cost())
print(test.get_down_pmt())
```

The total cost function works, but the get down payment method doesn't, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Calculate' object has no attribute '_Calculate__down_pmt'

Comment: Those getters and setters are pointless because: 1. This is Python, you can use property accessors; and 2. You can't actually pass a new value into the setters anyway. Also read up on leading double underscores and "name mangling".

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that **indentation matters** in Python!

Here is what your class should look like:

```
class Calculate():

    def set_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = 1000
        self.__total_cost = total_cost

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return self.__total_cost

    def set_down_pmt(self):
        down_pmt = 0.25
        self.__down_pmt = down_pmt

    def get_down_pmt(self):
        return self.__down_pmt
```

If the `get_down_pmt()` method isn't indented, it does not belong to your `Calculate` class.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have issues with white spaces.

```
class Calculate():
    def set_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = 1000
        self.__total_cost = total_cost
    def get_total_cost(self):
        return self.__total_cost
    def set_down_pmt(self):
        down_pmt = 0.25
        self.__down_pmt = down_pmt
    def get_down_pmt(self):
        return self.__down_pmt

test = Calculate()
test.set_total_cost()
test.set_down_pmt() 
print(test.get_total_cost())
print(test.get_down_pmt())
```

Output:

> 1000
>
> 0.25